# How to do a simple redirect in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes

I have a function in Laravel. At the end I want to redirect to another function. How do I do that in Laravel?

I tried something like:

```
return redirect()->route('listofclubs');
```

It doesn't work.
The route for "listofclubs" is:

```
Route::get("listofclubs","Clubs@listofclubs");
```

Comment: In your case you need to name the route

Comment: I think you may be referring to 
```return redirect()->action('Clubs@listofclubs');```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the **route path** you need to use the `to` method:

```
return redirect()->to('listofclubs');
```

If you want to use the `route` method you need to pass a **route name**, which means you need to add a name to the route definition. So if modify your route to have a name like so:

```
// The `as` attribute defines the route name
Route::get('listofclubs', ['as' => 'listofclubs', 'uses' => 'Clubs@listofclubs']);
```

Then you can use:

```
return redirect()->route('listofclubs');
```

You can read more about named routes in the [Laravel HTTP Routing Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes) and more about redirects in the `Redirector` class [API Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html) where you can see the available methods and what parameters each of them accepts.

Comment: You can also use the following line as your route: `Route::get("listofclubs","Clubs@listofclubs")->name('listofclubs');`           At least for me, it was easier to remember the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Simply name your route:

```
Route::get('listofclubs',[
    'uses' => 'Clubs@listofclubs',
    'as'   => 'listofclubs'
]);
```

Then later

```
return redirect()->route('listofclubs');
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to follow the solution provided by others. The other method would be, since you intend to call the function directly then you can use

```
return redirect()->action('Clubs@listofclubs');
```

Then in route file

```
Route::get("listofclubs","Clubs@listofclubs");
```

Laravel will automatically redirect to /listofclubs.