# How to do simple redirection in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, redirect

I am working on building my portfolio using Laravel. I am learning Laravel in the process of building my portfolio so I am very new to it.

I am trying to do a simple redirect using `Route`.

This is what I have written in **web.php**:

```
Route::patch('developer-profile',[
    'as' => 'developer-profile',
    'uses' => 'redirectionLinks@pleaseRedirect'
]);
```

This is how I am writing the HTML (It is bladed):

```
<a href="{{ route('developer-profile') }}">Developer Profile</a>
```

And this is how my controller is - **Redirection.php**:

```
namespace app\Http\Controllers;
use app\Http\Controllers\Controller;

public class redirectionLinks extends Controller{

    protected $guard = 'web'; //I am not using it anywhere, but I am searching for anything that I might have missed.

    public function pleaseRedirect(){
        return redirect('developer/developer-profile');
    }
};
```

I have tried to search [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364784/how-to-do-a-simple-redirect-in-laravel) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801911/how-to-make-instant-redirection-in-laravel) question, but it didnt really help.

I have gone through the following Documentation links from Laravel:

1. [HTTPControllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers)
2. [HTTPRedirects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects)

and a few more in the past few days whose links I couldn't find.

Am I missing  something here, because I seemed to have tried 5-10 basic approaches starting from the basic function as follows:

```
Route::get('/developer/developer-profile', function(){
    return view('developer/developer-profile');
})->name('developer-profile');
```

**EDIT:**

When I hit `php artisan route:list` in the CMD, I get the following error window:

[image: ReflectionException]

**UPDATE:**

I have changed the filename to `redirectionLinks.php` from `Redirection.php`. Now the above error when I hit `php artisan route:list` show me all the routes, but still the redirection is not happening as I get the following error:

[image: MethodNotAllowedException]

Please help me with my problem if anyone has a clue about what I am asking.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta rename your file to `redirectionsLinks.php` instead of `Redirection.php`, if this still doesn't work, try rebuilding the autoload: `composer dumpauto`.

Either that or doing this in the routes, and renaming your class to Redirection, should work:

```
Route::get('developer-profile',[
    'as' => 'developer-profile',
    'uses' => 'Redirection@pleaseRedirect'
]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I thought so that the issue is very small since I am not familiar with Laravel syntax.

Comment: Now I can see the updated routes when I hit `php artisan route:list`, but still I have an error that says `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Comment: use the get method instead of patch, why are you using patch? GET is for retrieving, POST is for sending. DELETE and PUT (which is the same as PATCH), work the same as post but you gotta send some hidden field, i dont remember the name since i've been using javascript for this since a long time...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, I thinks `patch` is from the time when I was trying every possible way to check what I have written wrong here.

Comment: yeah, POST, PUT/PATCH and DELETE are for sending forms, rather than consulting URLs which should always be GET

Comment: I have to ask one more question from you regarding the same, I have `developer-story.php` in `resources > views > developer > developer-story` and the above answer solved the redirection issue, am I making a mistake in writing the proper path to the php file, because it says `no such page found`.

Comment: change return `view('developer/developer-profile')` to `view('developer.developer-profile')` ... personally i have never used dash `-` to name my views, instead i use underscore `_` but i don't really know if this would affect you somehow... Check the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views  ... Look where it says nested views.